# sed regular expression behaving differently than in vim and perl?

Tags: sed, vim, regular-expression, perl

Here's a sample 'test.txt'

```
abcdX1yad45das
abcdX2fad45das
abcdX3had45das
abcdX4wad45das
abcdX5mad45das
```

sample desired output:

```
X1yad
X2fad
X3had
X4wad
X5mad
```

I could get it working in vim with:

```
:% s/\v.*(X\d)(.*)45.*/\1\2/
```

and worked in perl as well with:

```
open(my $file, "<", "test.txt");
while(<$file>)
{
    s/.*(X\d)(.*)45.*/$1$2/; 
    print $_;
}
```

*my eventual regular expression needs two groupings, it wasn't required for this example output*

am not able to get it work with sed:

```
sed -r 's/.*(X\d)(.*)45.*/\1\2/' test.txt
abcdX1yad45das
abcdX2fad45das
abcdX3had45das
abcdX4wad45das
abcdX5mad45das
```

just to check sed is working,

```
sed -r 's/(a)/#\1#/' test.txt
#a#bcdX1yad45das
#a#bcdX2fad45das
#a#bcdX3had45das
#a#bcdX4wad45das
#a#bcdX5mad45das
```

what am I doing wrong in sed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` does not understand `\d`.  You can use `[0-9]` or, more generally, `[[:digit:]]` in its place:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*(X[[:digit:]])(.*)45.*/\1\2/' test.txt
X1yad
X2fad
X3had
X4wad
X5mad
```

Note that `[[:digit:]]` is unicode-safe but `[0-9]` is not.

Comment: thanks, I think I've come across this before and forgot...

Comment: @spasic : On the contrary, vim do understand `[[:digit:]]` & `[0-9]`. You might wish to stick on with one format

Comment: yup, will keep this in mind.. but hard to change years of usage

Comment: Note `\d` and `[[:digit:]]` are the same, but `[0-9]` is different in (e.g.) Unicode where there are digit codepoints that are not within `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/abcd\(X[0-9][a-z]ad\)45das/\1/g' your_file_name
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You `sed` does not understand the special sequence `\d`. Replace `\d` with `[0-9]` or character class `[:digit:]`:

```
$ cat file.txt
abcdX1yad45das
abcdX2fad45das
abcdX3had45das
abcdX4wad45das
abcdX5mad45das

$ sed -nr 's/.*(X\d)(.*)45.*/\1\2/p' file.txt   

$ sed -nr 's/.*(X[0-9])(.*)45.*/\1\2/p' file.txt
X1yad
X2fad
X3had
X4wad
X5mad
```